# Использование <<<END END; внутри функции eval()

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть такая проблема:
нужно через функцию eval() вывести код

```
eval(echo <<<END
sometext
END;);
```

однако выдаются различные ошибки (разными вариантами пробовал писать)
при таком варианте написания выводит

```
unexpected $end in .../index.php(21) : eval()'d code on line 3
```

мне нужно использовать именно конструкцию <<< END END;, конструкция echo "123"; не тащит.

подскажите, как правильно написать это?

Comment: а пробовали вначале в одной переменной собрать все вместе, а потом просто `eval($var);`?

Хотя, почитайте внимательно, скорее всего нужно писать так

eval(echo <<<END
sometext
END
;);

при этом END должен быть в начале строки и единственным.

Comment: Угу, перевод строки в конце забыт:

> HEREDOC syntax is ended by the
> delimiter defined at the start,
> followed by a semicolon, **followed by a
> newline**

То есть так достаточно:

    eval('echo <<<END
    sometext
    END;
    ');

Comment: Спасибо, помог перенос точки с запятой после END. 
хоть я и не могу понять логику О_О

Comment: Логику понимать не надо, надо читать документацию :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, забыт перевод строки после END;

Во-вторых:

```
mixed eval ( string $code )
```

Где строка на входе? Итого:

```
eval("echo <<<END
sometext
END;
");
```